# How can I edit the workflow information page?

Tags: development, workflow

After my workflow starts, in one column of the record it shows my workflow status as a link (ex: In progress,complete). When I click this link it takes me to another page with the workflow history and details.

I want to edit this page and delete some links of this page to simplify it.

For example, I want to delete "Update active tasks of 'My Work flow name'  " and I don't want to show workflow history.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please add comments to the answer instead of making a new answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of WrkStat.aspx and modify it to look the way you want. Then, workflow.xml has a StatusPageUrl node. You should put the name of your customized version of the workflow status page there.

Comment: where is workflow.xml file for edit it?

Comment: I'm referring to the element manifest file in your workflow project in Visual Studio, which may be called Elements.xml. The xml file looks like: <Elements><Workflow>. . .</Workflow></Elements>